# Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:build on project 'foo': Could not build image:

Tags: java, maven, docker, spring-boot

We working in small team of 4 people. We using docker to deploy our services. One of the services is a java Spring Boot project which is deployed after building docker image with maven. To make docker image of Spring Boot service we use `mvn clean package dockerfile:build`.

The fun part is that my colleagues have no problem building docker image of Spring Boot service. And I get maven error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:build (default-cli) on project 'foo': Could not build image: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('osxkeychain')
```

I tried to remove all maven repositories from `.m2/repository`, restart docker, and remove all images.

Later I tried to run `mvn clean package dockerfile:build` in to two separate commands:

- `mvn package`, then
- `mvn docker:build`

`mvn package` passed, and `mvn docker:build` failed with the same error as shown above.

Maven version `3.5.4`,
Docker version `18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`,
OS: macOS mojave

I even tried to restart my PC hoping that it will fix it...

Edited:
Here is the maven pom plugin `dockerfile-maven-plugin`

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Edit 2:

Full error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.3.6:build (default) on project spring-boot-service: Could not build image: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.spotify.docker.client.messages.RegistryAuth: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('swarm')
[ERROR]  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["stackOrchestrator"])
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Edit 3:

docker-compose.yml

```
wrapper:
  image: spring-boot-service:latest
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
expose:
  - "8080"
links:
  - db
  - another-service
```

Solved:

In my case it was wrong version of `dockerfile-maven-plugin`. I used `1.3.6`, and `1.4.7` fixed the problem.

Thanks to [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3301492/boris)!

Update: One more thing!

Make sure when `mvn` finish build naming is correct, for example:

```
[INFO] Successfully built **spring-boot-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**
```

And `docker-compose.yml` should look like this:

```
...
wrapper:
  image: **spring-boot-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT**
...
```

Comment: Can you share the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` section of the POM file?

Comment: Updated the question :)

Comment: Sorry, it's not a Dockerfile but a Compose file.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the [dockerfile-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/tree/master/plugin) config:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${dockerfile-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <repository>${project.artifactId}</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**NOTE:** use the latest released version [1.4.7](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin)

This configures the plugin to build and push your image with a [single command](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven#consistent-build-lifecycle):

```bash
$ mvn clean deploy
```

If you only want to build the Docker image, run:

```bash
$ mvn clean package
```

Comment: The error stays the same. The second line of error is: `[ERROR]  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["stackOrchestrator"])`. Maybe it's docker configuration... But I changed nothing for docker configuration

Comment: Can you share the `Dockerfile`? Also does the behavior change if you update the version of the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` to [1.4.7](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/releases/tag/v1.4.7)?

Comment: `wrapper:
  image: spring-boot-service:latest
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  expose:
    - "8080"
  links:
    - db
    - another-service` edited the question

Comment: I will try to change version of `dockerfile-maven-plugin`

Comment: Version did the trick. I was able to `mvn clean package`. Now I can `docker-compose up`. Thank you! :) Is it possible to mark comment as an answer?

Comment: Updated the answer with the plugin version.

Comment: Using the latests version 1.4.7 of the dockerfile-maven-plugin really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Go to docker desktop
2. Open settings
3. Go to general and put tick on Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FJ6S.png)